# how can i handle pagination in asp.net C# MVC4 in advance search module?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pagination

Actually in my application there are two type of searching facility one is **Quack search and another is Advance search** 
and i use routing the url means when i use Quack search with computer then my url is

1) **http://www.example.com:1270/Computer-Company/Computer/1**

we have more TABS or BUTTON on screen like Projects,Services,Leads....etc by default selected company TABS/BUTTON you can click on any tabs/button
suppose you search with computer then by default company is searching, then you can click on Project, you can see the result computers project and url is like below

Computer-Projects/Computer/

and pagination is working also fine Because we have only one Searching text like computers
But my problem is in Advance search

***THERE ARE THE TWO TYPE OF PROBLEM***

=> when i search with multiple criteria like Company Name,Contact Person,Tags,....etc
       User may be search with all criteria or single criteria so ADVANCE SEARCH URL IS LIKE

3)**http://www.example.com:1270/AdvanceSearch/Company/1**

so please let me know how can i pass the all data from view to controller at pagination time.
so please let me know ***how can i pass the data from view to controller with the use of model***
Temporary i am passing  hidden data,But in controller side parameters write like

```
public ActionReslut Company(string companyName,string contactPerson,string country.....)
```

{
**that is not proper way**
}

Answer (score 0):

You should use a ViewModel that contains all the fields that you need in the search:

```
public class SearchParameters{
    string companyName {get;set;}
    string contactOerson {get;set;}
    string country {get;set;}
    ....
}
```

Your action:

```
public ActionReslut Company(SearchParameters searchParameters)
```

and then using these fields to filter your data.